# how to set a category as default category in Junit4 by maven

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, junit4

for examples, I have 2 categories `A.class` and `B.class` and some test methods with these 2 categories as follows:

```
@Test
@Category(A.class)
public void DemoTest1() {...}

@Test
@Category(B.class)
public void DemoTest2() {...}
```

my pom file as follows:

```
       <profile>
            <id>Quick</id>
            <properties>
                <included.groups>
                    A.class AND
                    B.class
                </included.groups>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>Full</id>
            <properties>
                <included.groups>               
                    B.class
                </included.groups>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

However, I have many tests without any category, and now I want to run them in  category `B.class`, but I don't want to add the category `B.class` for each test because the count is too large.

So, is there a method that can set the category of these tests to B.class as default category by maven, I mean that if a test without any category then it will run with category B.class as default.

thank you guys very much